# Reference counter issue in python

Tags: python

I want to know how many references an `object` has so i try this code :

```
import sys
a=98392839273923
print(sys.getrefcount(98392839273923))
```

And the result is `4`. How can python's garbage collector free up object's space when we don't need them anymore, when there are always some "internal variables" point to this number ?

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: Pythons garbage collection does that automatically, the fact that 4 variables has the specified value means (as far as I've understand pythons background optimization) that 4 variables (somewhere within python) currently hold that value, try it with lower numbers (1,2 etc..) and you would see a huge spike in the returned value

Comment: @rotemtal yeah, python's garbage colletor reclaim an object's space when their reference counter drop to 0. But how can it does it when there are always 4 variable in side python holding this value

Comment: You can read about this function and the internal implementation [here](http://groverlab.org/hnbfpr/2017-06-22-fun-with-sys-getrefcount.html), It explains it better than I can